# Excel: Repeat VBA script after word is finished

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still learning how to make scripts in VBA.
For now I want to create script converting text from cell to Unicode Little Endian Hex. I have script that works now only for first character. How should i apply loop to switch to next letter, add it to print and finish script when text is over?

```
Function Text2LE(Character As String)    
Dim x As Long
x = AscW(Character)
If x < 16 Then
  Text2LE = "000" & Hex(AscW(Character))
  Text2LE = Right(Text2LE, 2) & Left(Text2LE, 2)
ElseIf x < 256 Then
  Text2LE = "00" & Hex(AscW(Character))
  Text2LE = Right(Text2LE, 2) & Left(Text2LE, 2)
Else
  Text2LE = "0" & Hex(AscW(Character))
  Text2LE = Right(Text2LE, 2) & Left(Text2LE, 2)
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Look in to `MID()` and increment a character by one each loop.

Comment: Looks like that function handles 1 character. You need to look at the code that's *invoking* that function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel 2010 VBA step through a string and place one char into each cell in sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778819/excel-2010-vba-step-through-a-string-and-place-one-char-into-each-cell-in-sequen)

Comment: OK, thx for help with MID.
I made something like this and is working.
`Function Text2LE(Character As String)
Dim x As Long
Dim a As String
Dim i As Long
c = Len(Character)
For i = 1 To c
a = Mid(Character, i, 1)
x = AscW(a)
If x < 16 Then
  LE = "000" & Hex(AscW(a))
ElseIf x < 256 Then
  LE = "00" & Hex(AscW(a))
Else
  LE = "0" & Hex(AscW(a))
End If
  Text2 = Right(LE, 2) & Left(LE, 2)
  Text2LE = Text2LE + Text2
Next i
End Function
`

Answer (score 0):

you need something like to loop through the Character in the string and convert it using your function! Then Group the HEX together and display or consume! (Not to sure on the display of hex in debug window)

```
sub Convert()
 Dim i as long
 Dim string_to_convert as string
 Dim Hex as String

 For i = 1 to len(string_to_convert)
   Hex = Hex + Text2LE(Mid(string_to_convert, i, 1))
 Next i

 debug.Print Hex

end sub
```